# Embedded Visualforce is not working when I test as Login User

Tags: visualforce, javascript, standardlayout

I embedded visualforce page contains javascript in standard layout.It is working fine when I testing.But when I login as User and  test, it is not working at all,there also no error in javascript console.As soon as I logout as user and go to the page,it works.I already granted FLS to the user.Here is my code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" >
  <!-- Remote Objects declaration --> 
    <apex:remoteObjects jsNamespace="RemoteObjectModel">
        <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Opportunity" fields="Id">
            <!-- custom field added to the Contact object -->
            <apex:remoteObjectField name="isFlag__c" jsShorthand="isFlag"/>
        </apex:remoteObjectModel>
    </apex:remoteObjects>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var flag={!opportunity.isFlag__c};

   if(flag==true){
   var x =confirm("This opportunity has been moved more that three times");
   if(x==true){
      resetFlag();
   }
   }

   function resetFlag(){

     var record= new RemoteObjectModel.Opportunity({Id:'{!opportunity.Id}',isFlag:false});
     record.update(resetFlagCallback);

   }

   function resetFlagCallback(err,ids){

        if (err) { 
           displayError(err); 
        } else {
             var totalPageURL = window.location.toString();
             var protocalType= totalPageURL.split("//")[0];
             var tempbaseURL = totalPageURL.split("//")[1].split("/");
             var finalBaseURL = protocalType+'//'+tempbaseURL[0];

           window.top.location.href=finalBaseURL+"/Opportunty_to_Close?id="+{!opportunity.Id};
        }

   }

  </script>  
</apex:page>
```

What are possibles step/code that I missed?

Comment: Can you check, if login user profile has access of that embedded VF page?

Comment: Yes, to be sure I enable all Profile for that embedded VF Page.But it's not working.

Comment: Okay, then What is the sharing setting for Opportunity object. Does Login User has access to this Opportunity record?

Comment: Yes... The user can view and create Opportunity.I included visualforce inside Opportunity Standard Layout, the dialog box in the code does not popup at all while  user view the Opportunity.It doesnot run the script at all, but when I log out as user it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes stupid me.I am about to close the question but I am thinking that maybe another people repeat the same mistake.

The root cause is : Page Layout. I did not embed this Visualforce in the user page layout.

Apologize on inconvinience.